# Thread used for TCP Listening throws StackoverflowException

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, stack-overflow

I'm having problems listening for connections within a TCPListener, basically I am running this on a different thread as so:

```
listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));

void Listen(...)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Socket socket = Listener.AcceptSocket(); 
        Connection connection = new Connection(socket);
        connection.onInit();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Listen();
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to do next to solve this "Stackoverflow" Exception, I need to listen to connections on a different thread like the way I've coded it, any suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Listen()` is calling itself which will eventually result in a stack overflow.

Simply remove the call to `Listen()` at end of the while loop.

Comment: That won't let my thread to keep listening for other incoming connections.

Comment: Then you might have a design flaw!

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro: yes, of course it will. Your method simply loops, calling `Accept()` over and over. This is fine. Of course, somewhere you need to call `Receive()` to receive data. There's a lot more to a network-capable program than just accepting inbound connection requests. But you can at least avoid the infinitely-recursive call in your `Listen()` method. :)